# Are there technologies-S/w framework/tools/sites that do Translation from Indic(Indian) languages to English?

Tags: translation, hindi, tamil, indic

Are there any tools/sites which will allow me to enter some text in one of the many Indian Languages(Kannada,Marathi,Tamil,Hindi,..) and get translated it to English.
Google translate currently only supports Hindi among the Indian languages.

Comment: Interesting question. Although the answer will probably be "wait until Google Translate supports them" :)

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is quite an old question, but Google Translate now supports numerous Indic languages. As of today (15 June 2015) these are:

- Bengali
- Gujarati
- Hindi
- Kannada
- Malayalam
- Marathi
- Punjabi
- Sinhalese
- Tamil
- Telugu
- Urdu

I suspect the quality varies widely from language to language, but I do not know them well enough to compare.